# Unable to connect to Openfire from Spark on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, .net, xmpp, openfire

I have installed Openfire on my Mac localhost which us up and running. I have successfully created a test user. To test the connection, I have installed Spark 2.8.3 with entered following details as shown in the screenshots below

[image]

[image]

My Openfire config is

[image]

On attempting to Login via Spark, I keep running into "Unknown connection error. Please review Logs for more info" message and below are the packet info captured in Smack if it helps

Raw packets sent -

http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='admintest@localhost' xml:lang='en'>

http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='admintest@localhost' xml:lang='en'>
biwsbj1hZG1pbnRlc3Qscj0/VCklcUdSaj4lRltAai43fSZfPVEnKGF zPD93d0Fcdw==
Yz1iaXdzLHI9P1QpJXFHUmo+JUZbQGouN30mXz 1RJyhhczw/d3dBXHc1NjgzOWViNC1iZGEwLTQ3YWQtYWNhNC0yMzE4NzdkNmZiMzAscD1sVklSSmh3a3 dhYlJ1NFhOYm9IWHAzNkxtZFk9
http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='admintest@localhost' xml:lang='en'>

Raw packets Received -

PLAINSCRAM-SHA-1EXTERNALCRAM-MD5DIGEST-MD5zlib

PLAINSCRAM-SHA-1EXTERNALCRAM-MD5DIGEST-MD5zlib
cj0/VCklcUdSaj4lRltAai43fSZfPVEnKGFzPD 93d0FcdzU2ODM5ZWI0LWJkYTAtNDdhZC1hY2E0LTIzMTg3N2Q2ZmIzMCxzPVVOVDh1L3lZSVNFaE10UU tsSyt4M1Zab0Y3VEVzcDhnLGk9NDA5Ng==
dj1FYTBsY283Y2xnaS9CVjdobVJpNUo5S1c3Nl U9
zlib

Answer (score 0):

So, Spark is giving me a lot of problems to connect to my Openfire Server. As an alternative using Adium IM client and choosing XMPP Jabber connection resolved my issue. Spark mystery still remains.

Comment: So Adium  works fine on Mac OS and Spark works fine on Windows